# A Start Job is running for dev-md1.device

Tags: centos, filesystems, devices, root-filesystem

Hello everyone I'm with the following error on my CentOS 7
I restarted the server is now the boot time is with this message is already so minimum 40 minutes, what should I do?

[image: Print Screen]

Please Help-me?

Answer (score 1):

That means thesystem is trying to activate a software RAID device. Assuming you didn't recently change a disk or some such, just give it some time; it'll move on in a moment.

This may, howwever, indicate a disk failure. I suggest you check if your raid array is still fully functional:

```
cat /proc/mdstat
```

will give you an overview of your raid arrays and the disks assigned to them. Check that no disk is listed with a `(F)` marking, which indicates disk failure. Also, check that the raid array has no missing disk; you should see something like `[uuuu]` for a four-disk array. If one of the `u` letters is a `_` instead, that means the disk was not found by the software RAID. In both cases, I recommend you replace the disk.